# How to validate big XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, validation, nokogiri

I am trying to validate an XML file against an XSD using Nokogiri.
When the file is small I use document method validation:

```
xsd = Nokogiri::XML::Schema(File.read(Rails.root.join('files/xsd', self::XSD)))
xml = Nokogiri::XML(File.read(Rails.root.join('public/uploads', file_path)))
xsd.validate(xml).each do |error|
end
```

When the file is big, the previous method is not good because it needs a lot of resources, so I need file method validation:

```
xsd = Nokogiri::XML::Schema(File.read(Rails.root.join('files/xsd', self::XSD)))
xml = Rails.root.join('public/uploads', file_path).to_s
xsd.validate(xml).each do |error|
end
```

But the second way doesn't show me simple errors such as un-closed double quotes in the attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog version="123 xmlns="http://google.com">
   <book id="bk101">
```

and the first does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokogiri is a great tool for small to medium size XML, but when you get into large to extremely-large/huge files, you need to switch to other tools such as SAX parsing or, for validation, something like [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html).

> The xmllint program parses one or more XML files, specified on the command line as *`xmlfile`*. It prints various types of output, depending upon the options selected. It is useful for detecting errors both in XML code and in the XML parser itself.
>
> It is included in libxml2.